# How to parse a javascript variable declared in another document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

Consider this,

I have an external document saved into html variable:

```
var html="<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>My Title</title>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nvar my_var=\"12345\";\n</script>\n</head>\n<body>\n<div>\n<span>hello div</span>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
```

For ease of reading we can output this variable into console:

```
console.log(html)
```

This would output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_var="12345";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<span>hello div</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Jquery I was able to obtain and manipulate the values of dom elements.

For instance, I could read the contents of *span*:

```
console.log($('span',html).text());
```

Which would output:

```
hello div
```

However it is still unclear to me how to access the variables.

Having Jquery and Javascript at our disposal,

What would be the best way to retrieve the value of **my_var**?

Comment: The "variable" doesn't exist until you `eval()` the contents of the `<script>` block.

Comment: So this means regex would be the best way?

Comment: Or extract the `<script>` the same way you extracted that `<span>` and then `eval()` the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll go with regex then, because eval is obviously unsafe.

```
var matches= html.match(/my_var\s*=\s*['"](.+?)['"]\s*;/);
if (matches) console.log(matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an element without actually appending it into the document

```
var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.innerHTML = html;
var script = elem.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
eval(script.innerText);
console.log(my_var); //Should output my_var's value
```

Comment: Yeah but using eval in chrome extension while retrieving 3rd party pages is a really bad idea...